# read.table - long text split into different columns

Tags: r

I am trying to import the below data using the code below, the output I get has the long text split into different columns.

```
postcode <- read.table(file="workbook16.txt", header = T, fill = T)


Seq Suburb  Postcode
1   Melbourne   3000
2   Melbourne   3001
3   East Melbourne  3002
4   West Melbourne  3003
5   Melbourne   3004
6   World Trade Centre  3005
7   Southbank   3006
8   Docklands   3008
9   University Of Melbourne 3010
```

Where is my error?

Comment: I thinkt the issue is that the file might not be correctly separatated and you split on (single) spaces.

Comment: I tried doing that but it still separated names like "East Melbourne" into "East" and "Melbourne" into two separate columns.

Comment: If your input file looks the way I figured from your edit, this is a bit more work to get right. Something like, first column -> 1, last column -> 3, and rest in -> 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to read using `readLines`

```
lines <- readLines(n=10)
Seq Suburb  Postcode
1   Melbourne   3000
2   Melbourne   3001
3   East Melbourne  3002
4   West Melbourne  3003
5   Melbourne   3004
6   World Trade Centre  3005
7   Southbank   3006
8   Docklands   3008
9   University Of Melbourne 3010

lines1 <- lines[-1]
 dat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(lines1, '(?<=[0-9])\\s+|\\s+(?=[0-9])', perl=T)))
colnames(dat) <- lines[1]
colnames(dat) <- scan(text=lines[1],what="")
dat[,c(1,3)] <- lapply(dat[,c(1,3)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

dat
#  Seq                  Suburb Postcode
#1   1               Melbourne     3000
#2   2               Melbourne     3001
#3   3          East Melbourne     3002
#4   4          West Melbourne     3003
#5   5               Melbourne     3004
#6   6      World Trade Centre     3005
#7   7               Southbank     3006
#8   8               Docklands     3008
#9   9 University Of Melbourne     3010
```

Comment: You have been most helpful.

Comment: @Amit Verma. Glad it helped